# How to copy a file in pyspark / hadoop from python

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark to save a data frame as a parquet file or as a csv file with this:

```py
def write_df_as_parquet_file(df, path, mode="overwrite"):
    df = df.repartition(1)  # join partitions to produce 1 parquet file
    dfw = df.write.format("parquet").mode(mode)
    dfw.save(path)

def write_df_as_csv_file(df, path, mode="overwrite", header=True):
    df = df.repartition(1)  # join partitions to produce 1 csv file
    header = "true" if header else "false"
    dfw = df.write.format("csv").option("header", header).mode(mode)
    dfw.save(path)
```

But this saves the parquet/csv file inside a folder called `path`, where it saves a few other files that we don't need, in this way:

[image: 4 files are created in path, but we only care about the PARQUET file]

Image: https://ibb.co/9c1D8RL

Basically, I would like to create some function that saves the file to a location using the above methods, and then moves the CSV or PARQUET file to a new location. Like:

```py
def write_df_as_parquet_file(df, path, mode="overwrite"):
    # save df in one file inside tmp_folder
    df = df.repartition(1)  # join partitions to produce 1 parquet file
    dfw = df.write.format("parquet").mode(mode)
    tmp_folder = path + "TEMP"
    dfw.save(tmp_folder)

    # move parquet file from tmp_folder to path
    copy_file(tmp_folder + "*.parquet", path)
    remove_folder(tmp_folder)
```

How can I do that? How do I implement `copy_file` or `remove_folder`? I have seen a few solutions in scala, that use the Hadoop api for this, but I have not been able to make this work in python. I think I need to use sparkContext, but I am still learning Hadoop and have not found the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of Python's HDFS libraries to connect to your HDFS instance and then carry out whatever operations required.

From hdfs3 docs(https://hdfs3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html):

```
from hdfs3 import HDFileSystem
hdfs = HDFileSystem(host=<host>, port=<port>)
hdfs.mv(tmp_folder + "*.parquet", path)
```

Wrap the above in a function and you're good to go.

Note: i've just used hdfs3 as an example. You could also use hdfsCLI.

Comment: I had already found something like this but I don't know where to find the host and port. I am using a databricks instance which already sets up the environment for me, so I don't know exactly how it is configured. Maybe I should ask a separate question about this.